# Focus() doesnt show Keyboard

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want a keyboard to appear automatically. Focus() itself works, but the keyboard wont appear.

```
 tb_playerName.Focus();
 if (tb_playerName.IsFocused)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(); //debugger lands here but keyboard doesnt appear
    }
```

I tried implementing an interface and using the DependencyService for an platform-specific solution:

```
 public interface IKeyboardHelper //in xamarin.forms
    {
        void ShowKeyboard(Xamarin.Forms.View view);

        void HideKeyboard();
    }

 public class KeyboardHelper : IKeyboardHelper //in xamarin.android
    {
        public void ShowKeyboard(Xamarin.Forms.View view)
        {
            var renderer = RendererFactory.GetRenderer(view);
            Platform.SetRenderer(view, renderer);
            var viewGroup = renderer.View;
            var context = Forms.Context;
            var inputMethodManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
            viewGroup.RequestFocus();
            inputMethodManager.ToggleSoftInput(0, 0);
            return;

        }
    }
```

This also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

```
inputMethodManager.ToggleSoftInput(2, 1)
```

instead

```
inputMethodManager.ToggleSoftInput(0, 0)
```

Comment: 1. For some reasons the method wont accept 2 parameters and 2. I used   inputMethodManager.ToggleSoftInput(Android.Views.InputMethods.ShowFlags.Forced, HideSoftInputFlags.ImplicitOnly); instead of the two integers and it doesnt have any effect.  
Edit: It seems to be related to the Alert that appears before ShowKeyboard gets called.

Answer (score 0):

1. android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" was missing
2. I had to call the focus AND the dependency function, althrough the focus is requested in the function.

   await Task.Run(async () =>
   {
   await Task.Delay(500);
   tb_playerName.Focus();
   DependencyService.Get().ShowKeyboard(tb_playerName);
   });